# Remove duplicates based on second column

Tags: r, filter, duplicates, summarize

I am trying to write a section of code that does a few things:
 1) group dataset by ID
 2) count the number of unique months in column data.month
 3) remove all IDs that have less than 9 months
 4) print distinct IDs based on the company (ie print ID twice if related to 2 companies)
5) remove duplicated ID and keep the record that has the highest data.month number.

I have the code working until 5). I cant get my code to only print the record (row) of duplicate IDs that has the highest month number.

I looked at a few examples here:

[R remove duplicates based on other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51095249/r-remove-duplicates-based-on-other-columns)

[Remove duplicates based on 2nd column condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962909/remove-duplicates-based-on-2nd-column-condition)

I can figure out how to remove duplicates, but I'm having trouble applying it to my circumstances.

This is the two codes I have tried to achieve my goal:

```
data.check6 <- bind %>%
group_by(bind$ABN) %>%
summarise(count = n_distinct(data.month)) %>%
filter(count>8) %>%
rrange(bind$data.month) %>%
filter(row_number() == 1)
```

and:

```
 library(tidyverse)

 data.check7 <- bind %>%
  group_by(ABN)%>%      
  filter(1 == length(unique(bind$data.month)), !duplicated(bind$data.month))
```

Right now, I get the error:

> Error in arrange_impl(.data, dots) :    incorrect size (345343) at
>   position 1, expecting : 3749

In the end I would like to have a dataset where each ID only appears once and it is the ID record associated with the highest month (ie. column value = 12)

Comment: Please add a reproducible example along with expected output.

Comment: By your last sentence, I think you do not want to remove duplicates, otherwise you want apply a filter in a "group by". A reproducible example is very important in these cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like that:

**Example data:**

```
> bind <- data.frame(ABN = rep(1:3, 3),
+                    data.month = sample(1:12, 9),
+                    other.inf = runif(9))
> 
> bind
  ABN data.month other.inf
1   1         10 0.8102867
2   2          4 0.2919716
3   3          8 0.3391790
4   1          2 0.3698933
5   2          6 0.9155280
6   3          1 0.2680165
7   1          9 0.7541168
8   2          7 0.2018796
9   3         11 0.1546079
```

**Solution:**

```
> bind %>%
+   group_by(ABN) %>%      
+   filter(data.month == max(data.month))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   ABN [3]
    ABN data.month other.inf
  <int>      <int>     <dbl>
1     1         10     0.810
2     2          7     0.202
3     3         11     0.155
```

Comment: Yes, this  is what I was looking for. Thanks!